# Get rid of \\ in glob.glob

Tags: python, path, glob

I have the following code:

```
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Please choose a file directory", "File directory", 1)
EDS_database_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
EDS_answer = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "Please enter the ID")

EDS_files_list = glob.glob(EDS_database_path+'/**'+EDS_answer+'**', recursive = True)

print(EDS_files_list)
```

In the output I get:

```
['X:/data/Folder\\afilewithIDnumber.txt','X:/data/Folder\\anotherfilewithIDnumber.txt',]
```

So the function worked well but I want to get rid of "\" and replace it with "/" as I explicitly wanted to do in my function.

Comment: Not sure if you can modify the behaviour of `glob` but you could easily postprocess with e.g. `[filename.replace('\\', '/') for filename in EDS_files_list]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `print([filename.replace("\\", "/") for filename in EDS_files_list])` instead of `print(EDS_files_list)`. This will replace all instances of `\\` in the strings with `/`, which will make it output like you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the pathlib package in python3 as it the new normal for dealing with paths